# inserting csv data into sqllite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite

i have  a customers.csv with 1 column with 1000 records. i want to perform some operations on this, i want to insert this data into sqllite using python

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("customers.db")
cur = con.cursor()
#cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (cid);")

with open('CUSTOMER_SAMPLE.csv','r') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['Ssn']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (cid) VALUES (?);", to_db)
cur.execute("SELECT * from t")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

> i am getting an error 'Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
> current statement uses 1, and there are 11 supplied.'

Comment: `to_db = [[i['Ssn']] for i in dr]`. You need a nested list for `executemany`. Each sublist represents a single transaction, and wrapping in `()` doesn't do anything (it doesn't, for example, make a tuple which would also work e.g. `(i['Ssn'],)`  with the trailing comma)

Comment: As a debug aid, you can always print the data giving you problems. `print(data[:3])` would show the first several entries and identify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas `to_sql` method if you have to insert dataframe to sql table.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///customers.db', echo=False)

df = pd.read_csv("CUSTOMER_SAMPLE.csv")

df["Ssn"].to_sql('t', con=engine)
```

Comment: But that now brings in another tool without explaining why their existing code doesn't work, and could be easily fixed. Pandas is overkill

Comment: @roganjosh I gave an alternative answer

Comment: What answer? There was no other answer

Comment: @roganjosh https://stackoverflow.com/a/63308081/6849682

Comment: That didn't exist anywhere close to when you answered. That answer also has issues

Answer (score 1):

You only have one field (`cid`) supplied in the SQL command, but you are trying to substitute an list in.

Once the module completes the substitution, it ends up with a MySQL command that looks like this (say `to_db` just contains numbers):

`INSERT INTO t (cid) VALUES (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);`

The command is invalid because the amount of elements in your VALUES list is not the same length as the field list (`cid`). SQL doesn't know what to do with 1 through 10 in the list.

For example, let's say I have a table (named `people`) with columns `name`, `nickname`, and `favoriteColor` (which for the sake of this example and keeping it simple, are all of type MEDIUMTEXT). I want to insert the following person in to the table: Steven, who goes by Steve, and likes blue. I could do:

`INSERT INTO people (name, nickname, favoriteColor VALUES ('Steven', 'Steve', 'Blue')`

I could also do:

`INSERT INTO people (favoriteColor, name, nickname) VALUES ('Blue', 'Steven', 'Steve')`

Both of these SQL commands have the same result. The order of the list `(favoriteColor, name, nickname)` determines which values get put in which column. Since `favoriteColor` is first, the first value in VALUES (`Blue`) will get put in `favoriteColor`.

So, what you could do is iterate over the list `to_db` and add each record one at a time.

```
for value in to_db:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO t (cid) VALUES (%s)", (value))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Also note that there is no semicolon on the end of the SQL command, these are not needed as the library will take care of this for you in Python. You may put them there if you like; it's up to you.

Comment: While that might achieve the result, it doesn't address the problem that the OP is facing. Coupled with that, you _don't_ want to drop `executemany` just because it's currently throwing an error. Making individual transactions is terribly inefficient and the OP was on the right track

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there; the issue that you have is that `executemany` expects a nested structure, where each sub-sequence (list or tuple, for example) will be used for each transaction.

So,

```
to_db = [(i['Ssn']) for i in dr]
```

Creates a flat list. The parentheses in `(i['Ssn'])` don't do anything. You can fix this simply by making the entry a tuple by adding a comma:

```
to_db = [(i['Ssn'],) for i in dr]
```

You were correct to use `executemany` here so that the transaction can be batched. This is less significant in SQLite3 but would be more important if you were using Postgres or MySQL because that will require network traffic and the speed difference could be quite significant.